# Xcode 8 physically printing code in project

Tags: xcode, printing, xcode8

Bit of a weird one - is there any way to physically print out the code (e.g. on A4) in a project from Xcode?

Comment: Why not just open the code in a normal text viewer? Notepad++ will have that ability.

Comment: @Carcigenicate - would it keep the code formatting?

Comment: Notepad++ is made for viewing code. It will infer the language, and even give syntax highlighting. Great program.

Comment: does it work on mac?

Comment: More than likely. It's a very popular program. Just google it.

Comment: It doesn't but I can get round that.  However I'll have to put every file in separately.  Is there an easier way?

Comment: @Carcigenicate notepad++ doesn't support swift syntax